# Preloader and redirect in the same PHP script?

Tags: php

I have an application that runs a php script from a webform. The php script collects and sanitizes input from the form and processes the forms data. After this is complete the php script will load the findings in a results page. I would like to include a preloader page which would run from the php script while the script is executing and then load the results page. header() wont work as the script will run but then just stall on the preloader and never redirect to the results page. Basically I'm trying to the following:

```
<?php

header("Location: ./preloader.html");

// run code which includes parsing form 
// data that launched this php script on submit

$ch = curl_init("./result.html");
curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: you could render an image gif of a preloader, make an xmlhttprequest / fetch api, once done then get the response and put this in the result section

Comment: Is there xmlhttprequest equivalent in PHP?